# How to execute DOS' COMMAND.COM command from FASM?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, fasm

Is there any DOS function to execute string, containing command.com's line? I need something like C's `system()`, but for DOS and FASM.

Comment: Have you looked at [21h ah=4b](https://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-4b.html)?

Comment: There's also `int 2Eh`, but [it comes with some caveats](http://www.powernet.co.za/info/dos/int/2e.htm).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd That's one part of the puzzle.  OP also needs to find `COMSPEC` in the environment block to get the right interpreter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've previously used code like this to execute DOS shell commands.  It's for nasm, but you might be able to adapt it for your purposes.  This code specifically executes our own command line tail as a DOS command, but you can patch in some other command line tail if you want to execute a different command.

```
section .data
comspec db      "COMSPEC="      ; for finding COMSPEC in the env block
comlen  equ     $-comspec
command db      "COMMAND.COM",0

        ; EXEC parameter block
execpar dw      0               ; environment for child (use ours)
        dw      80h, 0h         ; command tail (use ours)
        dw      5Ch, 0h         ; first FCB (use ours)
        dw      6Ch, 0h         ; second FCB (use ours)

section .text
        ; execute DOS command
doexec:
        mov     bx, execpar     ; EXEC parameter block
        mov     [bx+4], cs      ; fix up segment for command tail
        mov     [bx+8], cs      ; fix up segment for first FCB
        mov     [bx+12], cs     ; fix up segment for second FCB

        call    fndcom          ; write pointer to COMSPEC value to DS:SI
        mov     dx, si
        mov     ax, 4B00h       ; LOAD AND EXECUTE PROGRAM
        int     21h
        jnc     .ok             ; error occured?

        push    ax              ; remember error code
        call    fndcom          ; find COMSPEC value anew
        pop     ax              ; restore error code
        call    perror          ; print error message

.ok:    push    cs              ; restore ds
        pop     ds

        ret

        ; find COMSPEC in the environment block
        ; and load pointer to it to DS:SI
        ; preserves bx
fndcom: mov     ds, [2Ch]       ; environment block
        xor     si, si          ; beginning of env block

        ; loop invariant: si points to the beginning of
        ; a string in the environment
.loop1: cmp     byte [si], 0    ; end of environment reached?
        je      .nope

        mov     di, comspec     ; find "COMSPEC="
        mov     cx, comlen      ;
        repe    cmpsb           ; compare strings
        je      .found          ; if found, we are done

        dec     si              ; go back to mismatched character
.loop2: lodsb                   ; search si for end of string
        test    al, al          ; end of string reached?
        jne     .loop2          ; nope

        jmp     .loop1          ; check next string in environment

        ; COMSPEC unset
.nope:  push    cs
        pop     ds              ; restore ds
        mov     si, command     ; "COMMAND.COM"
        ret

        ; COMSPEC found
.found: ret
```

The basic idea is to find the name of the command interpreter by searching for a variable named `COMSPEC` in the environment block.  If none is found, we default to `COMMAND.COM`.  Then, we build an [*exec parameter block*](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/355-exec_parameter_block__execparamrec_.html) with useful details for the program we would like to execute, including the command line.  This is where you need to put the shell command to be executed (in the format of a command line tail).  Finally, we invoke [DOS function 4b00: execute program](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/504-dos_fn_4b00h__execute_a_program.html) to execute the command interpreter, running our command.